# Pdf error in RStudio while extracting text from multiple pdf files

Tags: pdf, rstudio

I use pdf_text in RStudio and get the following error:
"PDF error: xref num 1 not found but needed, try to reconstruct<0a>"

Does someone have an idea what it means and what can be done about it?

Comment: thank you. can I check in R whether a pdf has a valid xref table?